# Kohana framework: how to know the element number within foreach?

Tags: php, foreach

This question is about Kohana framework. I'm new to it.

Using `foreach()` I want to display some data. Everything is fine, but I want to group that data 4 items in a row so it looks like:

```
1st 2nd 3rd 4th
5th 6th 7th 8th
9th 10th 11th 12th
....
```

That's why I have to add `<div>` every 4th time.

How do you make it? Do you use a simple counter and check if its mod is zero? Is there a special Kohana function to check the number of the current $item within foreach() if it is the first, the second or the n-th... item ?

```
<?foreach ($items as $item): ?>
//add <div> tag for 1st, 4th, 7th, etc item

//do something

//add closing </div> tag for 1st, 4th, 7th, etc item
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: `<?foreach ($items as $key => $item): ?>`  Add `$key =>` to get the current array key... When `$key % 4 == 0` close the `</div>`

Comment: Thank you. What's the reason my question was voted down? Is it unclear or duplicate?  Your answer is a solution for my question. If it were an answer, not a comment, I would marked this topic as solved.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. There are certainly similar questions out there already though I didn't go searching for one.  I can put my comment in as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `foreach` construct specifying the array key via `$key => $item`, you can test if `$key % 4 == 0` (or maybe `$key % 4 == 3` in your case) to close the open `<div>`.

```
// Initial opening div..
<div>
<?foreach ($items as $key => $item): ?>
 <?=$item ?>
 <? if ($key % 4 == 3): ?>
... Close the open div and open a new one
</div>
<div>
<? endif; ?>
<? endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

The templating syntax hurts my eyes. Here's proper PHP:

```
echo '<div>';
foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
  echo $item;

  if ($key % 4 == 3) {
    echo '</div><div>';
  }
}
echo '</div>';
```

Given the following input:

```
$items = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k');
// Output:
<div>abcd</div><div>efgh</div><div>ijk</div>
```